# Is it possible to compile only changes in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I made a C# compilation program with Roslyn. However, it takes about 1 second to compile the entire project.

I'm trying to optimize the time and here's my try:

```
// I'm currently recycling the compilation object.
if (compiler == null)
    compiler = CreateCompiler();

/* ... */

for (var tree in syntaxTrees) {
  SyntaxTree oldTree;

  if (PreviouslyAddedAndHasChanges(tree)) {
      compiler = compiler.ReplaceSyntaxTree(oldTree, tree);
  }
  else if (NewlyAdded(tree)) {
      compiler = compiler.AddSyntaxTree(tree);
  }
}

compiler.Emit(...);
```

But it doesn't work. Output assembly won't be changed.
I also take a look `EmitDifference` method, but it does not work with `.dll` output.

Here's my question:

1. Is it safe to re-use `CSharpCompilation` object just like my first line of the code?
2. Does `Roslyn` caching previous compilation data and should I invalidate it?

Comment: msbuild/C# does have _[incremental build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34590342/585968)_ though not sure how that carries through to Roslyn

Comment: You should be able to add and replace trees like you've done here. `compiler.Emit()` will return an `EmitResult`. Does it say it was successful?

Comment: @JoshVarty Yes, there was no error

Comment: Is it possible `PreviouslyAddedAndHasChanges()` or `NewlyAdded()` are both `false`? You have no `else`, so by default that would use the old compilation. Try also deleting the `.dll` from disk inbetween runs to make sure it's being emitted properly.

Comment: Actually, I used MemorySteram to emit & load the .dll. So, it is not possible to delete the previous .dll. 
However, I got a hint from your comment. The problem was `Assembly.Load` is not working because two assemblies have exactly the same name.

Comment: @JoshVarty It works well and x10 faster than before. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Self answer:
I fixed it now. The problem was not related with `Roslyn`.
The two assemblies have exactly the same name, so `Assembly.Load()` does not work at all.

Here's my solution to fix it.

```
compiler = compiler.WithAssemblyName("some_name" + (new System.Random()).Next(10000000));
```

And, the answers are:

1. Yes
2. I'm not sure, but it seems that they re-compile it if there is any changes.